# R plot function - axes for a line chart

Tags: r, plot, line

assume the following frequency table in R, which comes out of a survey:

```
      1  2  3  4  5  8
  m   5 16  3 16  5  0
  f  12 25  3 10  3  1
  NA  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

The rows stand for the gender of the survey respondent (male/female/no answer). The colums represent the answers to a question on a 5 point scale (let's say: 1= agree fully, 2 = agree somewhat, 3 = neither agree nor disagree, 4= disagree somewhat, 5 = disagree fully, 8 = no answer).

The data is stored in a dataframe called "slm", the gender variable is called "sex", the other variable is called "tv_serien".

My problem is, that I don't find a (in my opinion) proper way to create a line chart, where the x-axis represents the 5-point scale (plus the don't know answers) and the y-axis represents the frequencies for every point on the scale. Furthemore I want to create two lines (one for males, one for females).

My solution so far is the following:

1. I create a plot without plotting the "content" and the x-axis:

   ```
   plot(slm$tv_serien, xlim = c(1,6), ylim = c(0,100), type = "n", xaxt = "n")
   ```

The problem here is that it feels like cheating to specify the `xlim=c(1,6)`, because the raw scores of `slm$tv_serien`are 100 values. I tried also to to plot the variable via    `plot(factor(slm$tv_serien)...)`, but then it would still create a metric scale from 1 to 8 (because the dont know answer is 8).

So my first question is how to tell R that it should take the six distinct values (1 to 5 and 8) and take that as the x-axis?

2. I create the new x axis with proper labels:

   ```
   axis(1, 1:6, labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "DK"))
   ```

At least that works pretty well. ;-)

3. Next I create the line for the males:

   ```
   lines(1:5, table(slm$tv_serien[slm$sex == 1]), col = "blue")
   ```

The problem here is that there is no DK (=8) answer, so I manually have to specify `x = 1:5` instead of 1:6 in the "normal" case. My question here is, how to tell R to also draw the line for nonexisting values? For example, what would have happened, if no male had answered with 3, but I want a continuous line?

4. At last I create the line for females, which works well:

   ```
   lines(1:6, table(slm$tv_serien[slm$sex == 2], col = "red")
   ```

To summarize:

- How can I tell R to take the 6 distinct values of `slm$tv_serien` as the x axis?
- How can i draw continuous lines even if the line contains "0"?

Thanks for your help!

PS: Attached you find the current plot for the abovementiond functions.

PPS: I tried to make a list from "1." to "4." but it seems that every new list element started again with "1.". Sorry.

[image: line chart]

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but is a line chart even the best kind of visualization for this type of data? Since you're talking count, I would have thought a bar chart would have been more appropriate.

Comment: Some of the options I mention [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34776/suggestions-on-how-to-visualize-survey-data/34778#34778) might also be of interest to you....

Comment: Absolutely true. I just took this as an example. A bar chart would make more sense and I managed to create a nice one, but the problems I mentioned for my line chart still exist and would also be true for other (more appropriate) cases.

Comment: For your first question, a solution would be to use factors.  Convert your values (i.e. 1:5 and 8) into factors, and you can even name them appropriately, if you want.

Comment: @Frank: I tried, but if I'm using `plot(factor(slm$tv_serien)...)` I can't prevent the plot to be drawn via `type ="n"` because this is not speficied for plot.factor. So I always would get a barchart, which I don't want.

Comment: @Frank: I now tried to first make a factor `tv2 <- factor(slm$tv_serien, labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "DK"))`. But in doing so I afterwards have to treat the factor in the plot function as a numeric variable to get a line chart: `plot(table(as.numeric(tv2)), type = "l")`. That's not very straightforward for me to first create a factor variable which then has to be changed back into a numeric variable.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Response to OP's comment.

This directly creates a line chart of OP's data. Below this is the original answer using `ggplot`, which produces a far superior output.

Given the frequency table you provided,

```
df <- data.frame(t(freqTable))        # transpose (more suitable for plotting)
df <- cbind(Response=rownames(df),df) # add row names as first column

plot(as.numeric(df$Response),df$f,type="b",col="red", 
     xaxt="n", ylab="Count",xlab="Response")
lines(as.numeric(df$Response),df$m,type="b",col="blue")
axis(1,at=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),labels=c("Str.Agr.","Sl.Agr","Neither","Sl.Disagr","Str.Disagr","NA"))
```

Produces this, which seems like what you were looking for.
[image]

**Original Answer:**

Not quite what you asked for, but converting your frequency table to a data frame, `df`

```
df <- data.frame(freqTable)
df <- cbind(Gender=rownames(df),df)    # append rownames (Gender)
df <- df[-3,]                          # drop unknown gender
df
#   Gender X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X8
# m      m  5 16  3 16  5  0
# f      f 12 25  3 10  3  1

df <- df[-3,]     # remove unknown gender column

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
gg=melt(df)

labels <- c("Agree\nFully","Somewhat\nAgree","Neither Agree\nnor Disagree","Somewhat\nDisagree","Disagree\nFully", "No Answer")
ggp <- ggplot(gg,aes(x=variable,y=value))
ggp <- ggp + geom_bar(aes(fill=Gender), position="dodge", stat="identity")
ggp <- ggp + scale_x_discrete(labels=labels)
ggp <- ggp + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5))
ggp <- ggp + labs(x="", y="Frequency")
ggp
```

Produces this:
[image]

Or, this, which is much better:

```
ggp + facet_grid(Gender~.)
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I appreciate your suggestions. Of course, with the ggplot package you could build much prettier graphs than with the normal plot function. But honestly, that doesn't solve my problem. :/ I was just wondering what would be the best way to build a line chart with my given dataset. Also @Frank mentioned that bar chart would be more appropriate for the given data, and I know that. But again, please consider the data just as an example.